# How do you avoid the extra newline appended to each revprop when using svnadmin setrevprop?

Tags: svn

I am attempting to set a revprop using `svnadmin setrevprop /path/to/repos propname propfile -r 0`. Each time I set this property a trailing newline gets appended to the value.

My `propfile` does not contain any newlines at all. (that I am aware of)

This is svn 1.6.11, running the Collabnet Solaris binaries.

If it matters I used vi in Solaris to edit the file . Vi seems to claim that the file has no newlines at all.

When I do a propget I see this:
`my prop value`

`prompt#`

I also confirmed this by dumping revision 0 out of the repository.

The newline does make a big difference, as I am trying to set the `svn:sync-from-url` property to set up a mirror repos. When I try to run synchronize i get this as the output
`svnsync: No repository found in 'svn://myserver/myrepos`
`'`

(Note the newline in the output; thank goodness svn includes the quotes or I might never have figured this out!)

Comment: The only other way I can think to do this is to reload the repository, and edit the dump stream before the load. However reloading a 15 gig repository takes all night on my server, so I would rather avoid this. Also, it would be annoying to have to wipe out all my mirrors every time I need to make a url change to the master.

Comment: Does `svn propset --revprop` have the same problem? And do you have to use svnadmin?

Comment: Also what does `od -t x1 propfile` tell you. Do you see a newline at the end.

Comment: You may also want to try `echo -n text > propfile` which shoudn't include a new line in the file

Comment: You are right, `d -t x1 propfile` is showing the linefeed. Stupid lying vi.

Comment: Have I mentioned I hate vi? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mike Glad to help. I wrote an answer with the solution. You may want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Unix convention that editors put an extra LF at the end of the file. That prevents the shell prompt from appearing on the last line of the file when displaying its contents using `cat` among other things.

To make sure this is happening run `od -t x1 propfile` and you'll see that the last character is `0a`.

If that's the case you can use `echo -n text > propfile` to write some text in the file without adding that extra LF at the end.

You can then pass that file to `svnadmin setrevprop`.